# Error running PEPK app signing tool at command line (java -jar pepk.jar)

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-app-signing

I'm getting the output:

> Error: null

from the command (executed at the command line):

> java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=my.keystore --alias=x --output=my.output --encryptionkey=1243

Anyone any idea why or how to resolve it?

The "my.keystore" file exists and is a keystore.  The alias is correct and the "my.output" file doesn't exist.  I have changed the encryptionkey value in the example above but no matter what values I use I always get the same output.

I've tried double quoting the keystore and output values and providing (with quotes) full paths to the keystore file and the output file.  Still the same error output.  The jar is being executed because I get the usage help displayed if something is missing.  I've also tried running the command in different directories and ensured that the permissions in the output directory is correct.

I'm using java version:

> java version "9"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

on Windows 10.  (I've tried paths with both / and ).  The pepk.jar was downloaded on the same day this question was posted from the App Signing page on the Play Store for my app.

#### Update, with new version downloaded as of 17/Sep/2018:

After downloading the new version of pepk.jar as suggested by Pierre the output is now:

```
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.loadKeystore(KeystoreHelper.java:45)
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.getPrivateKey(KeystoreHelper.java:38)
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:114)
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:79)
```

I've double checked the keystore and it contains a private key, via the use of keytool -list -v -keystore.

Comment: Are you able to extract the certificate of the key when you run keytool? 
keytool -export -alias <alias> -file /tmp/cert.crt -keystore <your.keystore>

Comment: Yes, just tried the export and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you try again by downloading the latest version of pepk tool? I don't expect it to work better, but it should give us more information on the error.

Comment: Already tried that, got exactly the same result.  I've also examined the jar file with jar tvf and it seems valid, the help also pops up if one of the parameters is missing.

Comment: What I meant is that we've updated the pepk tool yesterday, so now you will get a stacktrace instead of just "null" which will give me more information to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Ah ok, I will try it tomorrow.  It wasn't clear that you were involved in the development of the tool.

Comment: I've updated the question after downloading and running the new version.

Answer (score 28):

You have atleast Java Version 8(JDK 1.8) to run the syntax:

> java -jar PATH_TO_PEPK --keystore=PATH_TO_KEYSTORE
>       --alias=ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK --output=PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE --encryptionkey=GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY

Legend:

- **PATH_TO_PEPK** = Path to the pepk.jar you downloaded, could be something like *C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\pepk.jar* for Windows users.
- **PATH_TO_KEYSTORE** = Path to keystore which you use to sign your release APK. Could be a file of type `*.keystore` or `*.jks` or without extension. Something like *C:\Android\mykeystore* or *C:\Android\mykeystore.keystore*.
- **ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK** = The name of the alias you use to sign the release APK.
- **PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE** = The path of the output file with `.pem` extension, something like *C:\Android\private_key.pem*
- **GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY** = This encryption key should be always the same. You can find it in the App Signing page, copy and paste it. Should be in this form: *eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a*

Example:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\pepk.jar"
--keystore="C:\Android\mykeystore" --alias=myalias --output="C:\Android\private_key.pem" --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a
```

After entering the command in the terminal, you will need to provide the following:

1. The keystore password
2. The alias password

If everything has gone OK, you now will have a file in `PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE` folder called `private_key.pem.`

More resources:

- [How to enable google play app signup official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing)
- [Step-by-step implementation blog](http://kungkurahan.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing.html)

Comment: I already updated JDK to latest version but still get same error. :(

Answer (score 13):

I finally got around this problem by using the standard Windows (10) command prompt, i.e. "cmd".  It seems that the System.getConsole is returning a non null value for cmd.

I haven't been able to find any information on what is happening with mingw64 (the command prompt I generally use on Windows) and why the System.getConsole isn't being set up.

Comment: this worked for me after trying to run in cygwin and git bash failed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally worked for me from PowerShell

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `gitbash`, you have to pre-fix the command with

```
winpty
```

as the `PEPK` command requires console input.
(or run is via a standard `windows CMD prompt`)

Comment: Wow thanks. I'd never have got there by myself!

Comment: Thank you very much. I've always got stuck on this and until now tried it on CMD instead of gitbash, But now I can use it on gitbash too.

Answer (score 5):

I really appreciate the response given by @droidBomb in previous Answer.

The solution for xamarin Android is slight different.
 REQUIRED FLAGS

--keystore            Path to the keystore containing the private key to export(Eg:C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\abc.keystore)"

--alias               Alias of the private key in the keystore(Eg:upload)

--encryptionkey       Public key to encrypt the private key with. This will be
                      be the hex encoded bytes of the public key. The public key
                      is a 4-byte identity followed by a 64-byte P256 point.(Eg: eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a)

--output              File in which to output the encrypted private key.(Eg:C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\private_key.pem)

1. Open the Command Prompt
2. Download the pepk file from Google Console of Your application.
3. Prepare the command like following
4. java -jar "C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\pepk.jar" --keystore="C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\upload.keystore" --alias="upload" --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a --output="C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\private_key.pem"

The respective pem file will be generated at output path

Comment: What is different between your answer and droidBomb's answer?  Looks like the same 4 required keys...  OR are you just pointing out the correct value of "encryptionkey" to use when uploading from an android app keystore to Google Developer Console, for use when enabling ["App Signing by Google Play"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)? [Which isn't specific to XAMARIN Android.]

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem when trying it on Windows 10 with gitbash / mingw64.
With Powershell it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The password for the keystore and the key are prompted on the command line.

The issue seems to be that your Java environment does not have a Console available, i.e. `System.console()` returns null.

If you're able to let me know what causes your Java environment to do this, then we might try to find a solution for your use case.

Comment: I've no idea as to the cause of why System.console returns null.  I am running it from a MINGW64 terminal on Windows 64.  i.e. a command line.  A test program shows System.console always returns null but System.out is redirecting to the terminal correctly.  I have enabled the Java console in the Java Control Panel but that made no difference.

Comment: Is there any update on this?  I've downloaded the tool again today and the same error occurs.  This is preventing us from updating our app in the Google store.

Comment: Do you run the command from a terminal inside an IDE by any chance? Looking at why the console is null, this is the first reason that comes up on the web. The alternatives unfortunately would not hide the password when you type it so I will keep looking at solutions but trying from a different terminal or someone else's computer might be your best bet for now.